# What is wrong behind my ALB on AWS that I get a 404 error (random)?

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, custom-error-pages

I have set an AWS application load balancer to redirect to IIS (ec2).
There will be more ec2 afterwards. For now, for testing purpose, I only redirect to this VM.
I also set an A record on Route53 pointing to the AWS balancer url.

Problem is that some times I reach the target, and sometimes I dont (with 404 error). Random.

For example, I visit:

http://labcac.netcontent.com.ar:8080/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css

It goes well. Once or twice. Third time, I get 404 error page.

Instead, If I use the public IP of IIS (instead of the Route53 record pointing to the ALB) it always works ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Listener

[image]

Comment: Since the request is answered by the IIS in both cases, this is not a Load Balancer Problem.

Comment: Can you add the snapshot of the listeners' rules you have defined for the ELB?

Comment: I've added snapshot of the listener

Comment: When I get a 404 page, the 404 page is still served by IIS. (The `Server` header is IIS, and the error page is the default IIS error page.) I think the ALB is still reaching your server. Do you have logs from IIS that might show why it's getting a 404?